# Can Selenium/Protractor be configured to execute a shell script?

Tags: shell, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing, angular9

I'm using Angular 9, webdriver-manager 12.1.7 and protractor 5.4.3.  In our end to end tests, I'd like to be able to execute a shell script and pass the result into my test so that it can be used.  The shell script requires an argument that is a result of some clicks from the test itself.  Is it possible to invoke a shell script from protractor/selenium?  As I discovered, this

```
import { ExpectedConditions as EC, browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
...
await browser.executeScript('./create_activities.sh', "arg1")
```

is for Javascript calls only, and results in the error

```
Failed: javascript error: Unexpected token '.'
```

Comment: Again that's outside the browser; as you note, the protractor executeScript method is to run a script *in the browser*.

Comment: This is definitely a no. executeScript and executeAsyncScript, runs a JavaScript function the runs in the browser session.

Comment: You need to use other nodejs package to run shell script, like shelljs